# Bootstrapping a bidirectional MOSFET switch?

Tags: mosfet, switches, ac, frequency, bidirectional

is it necessary to use a driver and bootstrap circuit in order to make this configuration work;

[image]

Or can I just stick 10V in it like shown?

This is to make a bidirectional switch, I'm not pulsing the MOSFET gates at a high frequency, simply turning it on or off depending on what I need, manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Or can I just stick 10V in it like shown?"

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/157872/68730

"Yes: however, your driver must be isolated as the gate nodes need to be Vgs(on) above the common source node. Photovoltaic isolator ICs or driver-transformer-rectifier combinations are usually used for this task -- either way, it's a switchable, isolated, low-current 10V gate supply. You'll want to work out how much current the isolated gate supply must pull, though (Qg is your friend here), so that you can determine if a PVI IC will suffice, or if the more-parts approach (transformer driver IC, small transformer, and rectifier) is needed."

There you go, if you stumble upon this.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to what he said 
there is an application note from IR , that you can use a high side driver for this purpose and add an external charge pump to make your bootstrap work on 100% duty cycle , i can search for that app note if you are still interested in the subject .
in this case no need for isolated power supply