# Must this switch be turned on and off periodically?

Tags: mosfet, switches, ac, signal, bridge

[image]

Imagine that the AC1-2 is 170VAC at 150kHz~.

I simply want to turn the MOSFETs on, and let the AC flow through a inductive-capacitive load.

1) If I can turn the MOSFETs on to saturation by applying a control voltage, is it okay just to leave them in saturation for however long I want to have the load active?

[image]

2) If I cannot turn the MOSFETs on to saturation by applying a control voltage, is it okay to use a bootstrap setup switching at the same frequency as the AC flowing through AC1-2 for however long I want to have the load active?

[image]

3) If all of this ends up being kind of shitty, what would you recommend I do? I kind of just want to have something that can pass 150kHz 170VAC as if it was a 'wire' i could 'turn on'. It's all just to add capacitance to a high voltage inductor.

[image]

At this point, any help would be appreciated, and I hope I've been clear.

Comment: I think I might be asking too many questions at a time or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes: however, your driver must be isolated as the gate nodes need to be Vgs(on) above the common source node.  [Photovoltaic isolator ICs](http://www.irf.com/product/_/N~1njcib) or driver-transformer-rectifier combinations are usually used for this task -- either way, it's a switchable, isolated, low-current 10V gate supply.  You'll want to work out how much current the isolated gate supply must pull, though (Q<sub>g</sub> is your friend here), so that you can determine if a PVI IC will suffice, or if the more-parts approach ([transformer driver IC](http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/1059/part/MAX253), small transformer, and rectifier) is needed.

2) N/A -- 1) is certainly possible

3) A mechanical relay could be used instead; however, you would need to be very careful to snub the relay's contacts correctly lest you get a pile of arcs and sparks every time the relay switches.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll start working on it. I'm kind of confused on something though, when you say 'isolated because it needs to be Vgs(on) above Vs', does that mean that this circuit should not have common ground with the H-bridge that is providing power to it? Or do you mean I should simply have the 10V going through a transformer and still heading to common ground? Because I'm assuming that if the latter is true, the circuit will never actually be 10V above Vgs(on), and it would need to be driven by a bootstrap configuration in order to hit that Vgs(on) + 10V which is 170 + 10V. Like an H-bridge.

Comment: And AFAIK you can't bootstrap 100% duty cycle.

Comment: Oh, wait, yeah it shouldn't have common ground. Ignore that, I got kinda confused. So if it's isolated the 'ground' for the driver is simply the common node, and if the driver is hitting 10V (Vgs(on)) out, that's going to be Vgs(on) + common node voltage.

Comment: @ARMATAV -- yep.  The isolated driver means you don't have to faff with any bootstrapping or any other shenanigans

Comment: Beautiful. I'll grab another isolated DC supply and use that to drive the FETs. If you're still around, 12V is good enough to force IXTK120n25p out of it's linear region at 2A, right? 
Datasheet; http://ixdev.ixys.com/DataSheet/99175.pdf Just want to make sure I'm reading it right, at Fig. 7, for example, the admittance is crossing and highest at around 8V, and also this is good for 100% duty cycle at the gates of the FETs, right? (Just making sure we're on the same page with that, this is literally a 'switch' that is 'on' for like 15 minutes or however long I feel like leaving it on, no wave)

Comment: 12V will be plenty to turn a typical FET (like yours) on all the way, and 100% duty cycle saturation operation isn't a problem for a FET like this provided the power dissipation isn't excessive, of course.

Comment: Alrighty, awesome! Heatsinks, thermal paste and open air then.

Comment: Wait a sec, was I right about looking at Fig. 7 to find the point at which the conduction path 'ticks' out of the linear region?

Comment: Cause if I was, that was a pretty good guess.

Comment: @ARMATAV -- yeah -- the admittance and transconductance curves are the places to look for that :)

Comment: Haha! Yesssssssss!

Comment: Does this shift register driven PVI setup look good to you? http://i.imgur.com/ODJzyEG.png (Ignore the FET type, they are placeholders, so is the PVI chip)

Comment: @ARMATAV -- you'll need to stack two PVI ICs in series to get 10V out, but otherwise, you're on the right track :)

Comment: Kaboom, http://imgur.com/Rf39pmx I think I'm done here. I hope the BSR has enough current to open the little transistors that will provide current to the PVIs.

Comment: Hey, just coming back to this; can I use http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOK42S60.pdf with one of these http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/pvin.pdf Won't the 10uA low current just cause it to overheat at 4A 150kHz, 170VAC? It's got around 8ms of time switching on.

Comment: @ARMATAV -- you'll need to drive it somewhat harder, yes -- 8ms is too slow a switching speed for 4A @ 170VAC as per the SOA graph in figure 11 of your MOSFET D/S -- getting it down to 1ms or better will be needed to avoid cooking the FET

Comment: But I thought the other isolators didn't actually 'output' anything, and were just used as an amplifier. Aren't these PVIs with photodiodes the only things that can actually 'create' voltage? So would something like this work; http://www.vishay.com/docs/83609/h11b1.pdf

Comment: @ARMATAV -- look at my "more parts" approach in the answer -- a driver+transformer+rectifier can generate all the current you'll ever want, at the cost of parts count.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I kinda wanted to try the PVI approach just to see. But it's alright, I'll save that for later. I'm still a bit confused about the more-parts thing though, for example a 12V 2A wall-wart is a transformer + rectifier + regulator; can't I just use one of those?

Comment: Context: some other guy told me I still need to use a FET driver IC even though I'm using a wall-wart directly.

Comment: @ARMATAV -- no, look at the transformer driver IC datasheet I linked.

Comment: I see, so it's an amalgamation of everything I'd need to drive this in an IC, and you grab a primary/secondary ratio to match your MOSFETs, then you have a driver and a GDT essentially. I think I'll do that, however; is it possible to use an isolated 15V supply and an opto-isolator switch? Or was that just a bad line of thinking?

Comment: @ARMATAV -- channel-to-channel isolation'd kill you if you tried to share a single isolated secondary-side supply between multiple switch channels

Comment: I really can't wrap my head around why this would somehow couple and kill me. http://imgur.com/XUkuOqo That's what I mean by using a wall-wart. Is the 15V going to jump it's isolation transformer, jump back into mains, then jump into my other 12V isolation transformer and into me if one part fails? I literally don't know.

Comment: @ARMATAV -- it was a figure of speech :) it'd cross-couple from one channel to another, causing everything to quit working.

Comment: Oh, really? I thought it would be safe because they were two separate ISO transformers. Alright. I guess I'll have to use an IC like you recommended. Is there a less complex IC than the one you linked? It seems I'll have to wind or buy little GDTs; couldn't I just use two floating supply drivers or even low side drivers instead, or would it still cross-couple and break my circuit? I'm a little confused about cross coupling in general, sorry if I'm being a pain with all the questions.

Comment: Actually, I think it's super easy and I'm just looking at it wrong. I've totally got this now. I will use your MAX253. I still wish I could just use a second wall wart and opto-coupler plus transistor control though. But whatever, if this works, great! Anyway, thank your for the help. I think everything will go smoothly. Just gotta rectify the output on the secondary of the MAX253.

Comment: Hey, back again, just grabbing a decent SMD transformer, do you think this is one suited to the job (I'm gonna have 3 of these AC switches, so 3 MAX253s and I guess one of these) http://www.amgistoroids.com/assets/files/ISDN%20SO%20Miniature%20SMD%20Interface%20Modules.pdf

Comment: Perhaps this, actually; http://www.murata-ps.com/data/magnetics/kmp_78253.pdf It's going to be switching the capacitance of what is essentially a Tesla Coil, so I need to avoid inductance levels that could accidentally couple with the primary, which this circuit is right next to.

Comment: Just kidding, the resonant frequency of the first one is in the mHz range; my coil runs at like 150kHz; I should be good.

Comment: Looks like we lose, the AC just sees the MOSFETs as short circuits because of their output capacitance. Sucks. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171701/calculating-signal-attenuation-for-ac?noredirect=1#comment349833_171701